# Google Sheet function to Split the Data Accordingly

Tags: google-sheets

I have a worksheet being fed by a Google Form. I want the responses on the Google Form to populate two fields in the next tab. The B column in the second tab is the one beyond my skillset. I have written out how the field should display, based on the form responses for reference. I also have used comments on the sheet to explain the rules for each field.

I know split function can be used but it wont adjust it. any possible solution.

Here the Sheet link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ueKCNdcn1xmJHYtrzKKKkj_FSraRfpvJS4Oi3BHNUvk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added an answer on your sheet.  Since the data is all delineated by semi-colons, this formula seems to match what you want.

```
=SPLIT('Import Data'!B1,";",0,0)
```

Let us know if it doesn't do what you want, or if this helps.

Updated: After checking with you, I realise that you want only some of the data split, and some kept concatenated.  But since all of the data "fields" look the same, separated by semi-colons, and since there could be various numbers of fields in each response category, I don't think there is a simple logic that can tell where to split, and where to keep things like dress styles or sizes concatenated.  So I understand that this is not your desired answer.